# Android Webview - How to use evaluateJavascript when javascript function accepts arguments?

Tags: android, webview

I would like to call a javascript function in my webview using `evaluatejavascript` method but I don't know how to use it when the function accepts arguments.

My webview:

```
webView1.evaluateJavascript("download(11852,'c595b0ec8c')", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
         Log.d("LogName", s); 
    }
});
```

This does not seem to work. I have read in android api docs that the first argument in `evaluateJavascript` is the javascript function code(in String) NOT the CALL to the javascript. So how would I execute the javascript with arguments?

This is the javascript function:

```
function download(songId, key)
{
    var form = document.getElementById('dlForm');
    form.action = '/download/zephzeph/' + key + '/' + songId + '.mp3';
    form.submit();
}
```

Is this possible? Any sugggestions and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function is defined in the displayed page? Is JavaScript enabled in your WebView? Could you add a return value to the function to see if it returns it to the callback?

Comment: @StenSoft -Yes the function is defined in the display page. Javascript is enabled in my webview as well. How do I add the return value? Btw this is the site gendou.com/amusic. You need to be logged in to the site in order for the javascript function to be called. The function will trigger when you click on the name of the song.

Answer (score 0):

You code just defines a function without calling it. So you need to call it in the JavaScript code therefore the arguments will be specified in the string that is passed to `evaluateJavascript`.